# Java hardcoded repeating process

Tags: java, oop, loops, hardcode

I am making a basic hardcoded game that has 2 users that will fight each other.  All my methods are set and work as expected.  I am now trying to figure out a way after looping through the main hardcode, to give the option to fight again and continue the game, instead of just stopping after 1 fight.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your name: ");
        String myName = in.nextLine();

        Fighter a = new Warrior();
        Fighter b = new Dragon();
        a.pickOpponent(b);

        a.setName(myName);
        b.setName("Onyxia");

        System.out.print(getWelcome());     
        while(in.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            switch(in.nextLine()) 
            {
                case "no":
                    System.out.println("Wow, you are not even gonna try, you have lost!");
                    break;
                case "yes":
                    System.out.println("Let the fight begin! ");
                    while(a.isAlive() && b.isAlive()) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Do you want to punch, kick, or headbutt the other fighter? ");
                        switch(in.nextLine()) 
                        {
                            case "punch":
                                System.out.println(a.getPunch(b));
                                System.out.println(b.getOpponentAttack(a));
                                break;
                            case "kick":
                                System.out.println(a.getKick(b));
                                System.out.println(b.getOpponentAttack(a));
                                break;
                            case "headbutt":
                                System.out.println(a.getHeadbutt(b));
                                System.out.println(b.getOpponentAttack(a));
                                break;
                            default :
                                System.out.println(invalidInput());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    System.out.println(a.getWinner(b));
                    break;  
            }//end of first switch statement
        }//end of first while loop
    }//end of main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving all of the code in `main` into a new function.

You can put that function into a while loop in your `main` method, like so:

```
while(playGame()) {}
```

and have `playGame()` return `true` if the came should be played again, and `false` if it should end.

---

Sample:

```
public static boolean playGame() {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is your name: ");
        String myName = in.nextLine();

        Fighter a = new Warrior();
        Fighter b = new Dragon();
        a.pickOpponent(b);

        a.setName(myName);
        b.setName("Onyxia");

        System.out.print(getWelcome());     
        while(in.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            switch(in.nextLine()) 
            {
                case "no":
                    System.out.println("Wow, you are not even gonna try, you have lost!");
                    break;
                case "yes":
                    System.out.println("Let the fight begin! ");
                    while(a.isAlive() && b.isAlive()) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Do you want to punch, kick, or headbutt the other fighter? ");
                        switch(in.nextLine()) 
                        {
                            case "punch":
                                System.out.println(a.getPunch(b));
                                System.out.println(b.getOpponentAttack(a));
                                break;
                            case "kick":
                                System.out.println(a.getKick(b));
                                System.out.println(b.getOpponentAttack(a));
                                break;
                            case "headbutt":
                                System.out.println(a.getHeadbutt(b));
                                System.out.println(b.getOpponentAttack(a));
                                break;
                            default :
                                System.out.println(invalidInput());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    System.out.println(a.getWinner(b));
                    break;  
            }//end of first switch statement
        }//end of first while loop
    }//end of playGame  

public static void main(String[] args) {

    while(playGame()) {}

}
```

Comment: so it should be a boolean then instead of an int? for the playGame method.

Comment: Are you sure ints as booleans works like that in java? I was unaware (although ive seen it in c++)

Comment: @BenKnoble I just checked and you are right. Seems like they don't work like that- the perils of programming in many languages... :)

Comment: Typing system.out.println is such an awful habit; it never works in c#

Answer (score 0):

I'd put `while(true)` above `System.out.print(getWelcome());` and closing it right before you close main. Then you can ask the user something like

```
System.out.println("Dare yie try again?");
String answer = in.nextLine();
if(answer.equals("yes"))
    break; //which would break out of the while loop.
```